# How to do two actions in one action of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create some text. I have a create action:

```
def create
  @text = Text.new(text_params)

  if @text.save
    redirect_to text_path(@text), notice: "Text successfully created"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

and the form:

```
<%= form_for @text do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Text name</label>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description</label>
      <%= f.text_area :description%>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

<%end%>
```

I need to have two action when I am submitting my text. The first action is going to create a text. The second is to create words out of the text words and should make a list of words.

When creating a word I need to have an `if` statement create a word if not present.

---

I am now having an issue with how I can split and create each word:

```
def create_words
  @text.split(/\W+/)
  @text.each do |splitted|
    if splitted !== @words.name
      splitted = @word
      @word.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should create an `after_create` callback in the Text class.  Then you `.split` the text and check the presence of each word in the DB with `find_by_word` (Or whatever Word's attribute is for the word).  This functionality does not belong in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! What I am doing wrong with .split can you suggest me please. I placed my code above

Comment: You are splitting, but then trying to iterate over the whole `@text` value.  Try `@text.split(/\W+/).each do |splitted|...`  Also you have to look up `splitted` in Word with something like (psuedocode) `if Word.where(value: splitted).empty? then save it`.  Based on what I see, I'm not certain if the Word model exists, which I would recommend you create if not.  If you don't understand that I'm afraid you have more fundamental problems to address, specifically creating Model Associations in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do your words thing in an `after_create` callback.

```
class Text < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_words


  private

  def create_words
    # do your thing here
  end
end
```

`create_words` will be called when a Text is successfully created.

Comment: that is great but I am now having an issue with how I can split and add each word to my database

Comment: Well, that's a different question.